# Konsole split screen replicates the same terminal

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, plasma-5, konsole

I've just installed Kubuntu 18.04 and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>)</kbd> in konsole, the screen is split in two, but they are the same terminal: what I type in one of them gets typed in the other.

I don't want two views of the same terminal, I want to open a different terminal, just like what you do with terminator.

Some info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

$ kded5 --version
kded5 5.44.0

$ kded4 --version
Qt: 4.8.7
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.38
KDE Daemon: 4.14.38
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid the split view has a limited function different than what you want. It allows you to view different parts of the **same** screen. That's it.

Here's [an old article](https://www.linux.com/learn/expert-tips-and-tricks-kate-and-konsole) that covers the issue. From there:

> Let's start with View -> Split View, which is a source of confusion
>   because the split is a clone, not an independent window.
>
> The purpose of this is to give two views of the same document or
>   whatever output you are monitoring. For example, suppose you are
>   studying a long configuration file. The split view shows the same
>   document in both panes, but you can scroll independently to bring up
>   different sections of the document side-by-side.

As far as konsole goes, you'll need to open a new window and arrange them to meet your needs. You could resize them and drag the windows to position them the way you want or use kwin shortcut to, for example, "snap" the windows to occupy half your machine's screen using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>.

---

The workaround, is first to open a new tab, and then use split view. Work in one tab in one view and work in another tab in the other view. They'll be independent. You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between tabs.

**Using tabs and split view:**

[image: Tabs and split view]

---

And here's [a reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/653u8h/terminator_functionality_in_konsole/) on using Yakuake which splits screens the way you want.

Comment: gee, that's a really odd, and not very useful, behavior... gonna have to stick with terminator ot tilix for a long while...

Comment: I am not 100% sure this answer is correct. The behavior on my Arch Linux and Manjaro installations is actually exactly as @opensas expected. `Ctrl`+`(` is configured as a shortcut for "Split View Left/Right" and `Ctrl` + `)` for "Top/Bottom". And at least I don't recall changing any setting besides the color scheme.

Comment: Yup, my terminal works as expected, no "cloning" on split, simply new "independent terminals" on the split view.

Comment: This is not correct, but it's not really your fault, blame the documentation team.
What happened is just that Konsole was started with the "broadcast all" option enabled. There are several ways to set / unset that. It is also possible to set up a layout and save it as a JSON file. Neither of these options is really well documented, pity. Basically, Konsole offers similar options as Terminator.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dropdown on the menubar, usually right of the "split window" menu, there you have 3 options "None" "All tabs current window" and "Select Tabs..."

Just press "None" and problem solved.

It is possible that this option is not shown on the menu or that you prefer to set a keyboard combination (as in Tmux or Terminator, for instance). You can do both from the Konsole settings or pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+,` or  `CTRL+ALT+,`

The latter command is also pretty useful to find which keyboard shortcuts are set and which are available, as this doesn't seem to have been documented elsewhere